# I need to specify the "dayMaxEvents" option in the "multiMonthYear" view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

In the "multiMonthYear" view on a day with eight events, the "moreLinks" option appears, which prevents me from seeing all the events directly, without the need to use the popup.

If I use only a month column or use the month view, the events are displayed as a dropdown.

In the "multiMonthYear" view with two columns, I need that if a day has eight events, they are all seen at once, without the "moreLink" option appearing.

The height of that day's block can grow as much as necessary.

I don't care if it doesn't match the next month's block next to it.

Is there a way to configure this?

Comment: This sounds like a custom view, not a default part of fullcalendar. We'll need more info, and some relevant code I think, before we can help you much. See also [ask]

Comment: Hello. I have edited my post. But does anyone know if this option can be set? In old versions of Fullcalendar, there was a year view, where the events were not hidden. Now the more option appears, but for my project it is a problem. I need to see all the events at once, without having to hit the more option. Thank you.

Comment: `In old versions of Fullcalendar, there was a year view`...no, there's never been a year view (you can still check the old versions of the documentation). That must have been something custom added-on to your fullcalendar, too.

Comment: `Finally I was able to achieve it`...that's great, but the Answer is not part of the Question! You need to add that info below, in the Answers area, so that it can be searched etc by others, and they can also upvote it if they find it helpful. Right now, to others, your question appears to be un-answered and will rank lower in searches. Please take the [tour] if you're unsure how Stackoverflow's question and answer format works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to achieve it by changing a series of css styles. But, I wanted to know if there was any configuration parameter to do this easily. The styles I've had to change are:

```
.fc-daygrid-event { 
    white-space: normal !important; 
 }
.fc-event-main-frame { 
    flex-flow: column !important; 
 }
.fc-daygrid-day-events { 
    position: relative !important; 
 }
.fc .fc-daygrid-event-harness-abs {
    visibility: visible !important; 
    position: relative !important; 
 }
.fc-daygrid-day-bottom {
    display: none !important;
}
```